# Is there a way to make a random variable into one that isn't random?

Tags: python, random

I am experimenting and studying a lot about programming lately. I want to write a guessing game in python, where the pc guesses a number in a range defined by the user. The way I have written this part is like so:

```
low = int(input("Choose the smaller number: "))
high = int(input("Choose the higher number: "))
num = random.randint(low, high)
pc_guess = input("Is this number correct: "+ str(num)+ "?")
```

If the answer isn't correct the computer will ask if their guess was high or low. What I wanted to do, was set a new range based on the computer's guess (for example, if the guess was too high, the new ceiling would be the guess minus 1). The guessing game concept isn't new to me, I wanted to try and write it more dynamically, test myself. But I realized I didn't know the answer to this question, is there any way to take the value of a previous random number, and assign it to a variable that isn't random?

Comment: num already insnt random anymore? Its a fixed value until you change it again

Comment: It seems like you want to write some sort of randomized [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), where you narrow down the interval, but instead of asking for exactly the middle value (leading to the fastest convergence) you just ask for any random value in the interval. Is this correct, and if so, what is the actual question?

Comment: Eumel, I didn't actually know that, I assumed it wasn't. I never ran into this until now. Thanks of explaining! I actually was able to write my program the way I envisioned. Though, thanks to my lack of knowledge I learned some things through you and the other answers. Thank you

Comment: None of them were the answer, so I'm not going to mark them. I can't mark the comment that informed me of the misconception I had. So yeah, I'm not going to delete this either, as it may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I see it work out:

```
low = int(input("Choose the smaller number: "))
high = int(input("Choose the higher number: "))
pc_guess = 'n'
while pc_guess == 'n':
    num = random.randint(low, high)
    pc_guess = input("Is this number correct: "+ str(num)+ "? (y/n)")

    if pc_guess == 'n':
        new = input("Is it higher or lower? (h/l)")
        if new == 'h':
            low = num + 1
        elif new == 'l':
            high = num - 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I actually was able to write my code how I initially envisioned, due to learning about a misconception I had. Your post was really similar to how I wanted to write it, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

For each randomized guess, adjust the corresponding limit e.g. `low` if the guess was lower than the number to guess and `high` otherwise.

```
import random

low = 0
high = 20
num = random.randint(low, high)

print(f"Number to guess: {num}")

while True:
    pc_guess = random.randint(low, high)
    print(f"Is this number correct: {pc_guess}?")

    if pc_guess == num:
        print("\tYes!")
        break
    elif pc_guess < num:
        print("\tNo. Higher")
        low = pc_guess + 1
    elif pc_guess > num:
        print("\tNo. Lower")
        high = pc_guess - 1
```

**Output**

```
Number to guess: 13
Is this number correct: 16?
    No. Lower
Is this number correct: 3?
    No. Higher
Is this number correct: 5?
    No. Higher
Is this number correct: 14?
    No. Lower
Is this number correct: 8?
    No. Higher
Is this number correct: 12?
    No. Higher
Is this number correct: 13?
    Yes!
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I actually was able to write my code how I initially envisioned, due to learning about a misconception I had. Your post was really different to how I was able to do it though, thank you for showing me a different way to think.